# Azure map style "blank" color change few days ago (changed to black to beige)

Tags: azure, maps, azure-maps

Azure map "blank"  style map background color changed automatically to beige before that it's black
its also got changed in azure map samples.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zGsM.png)

Please let me guide how I can change it to black.

I need only blank map not other style

I have also tried to change map div style as mentioned in Azure map documents

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcP2i.png)

Also try to change in its js/ css .

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Nikhil Patel

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

certainly a regression in a recent style update that is gradually getting rolled out for some users using `MapControl 2.2.5` or above. (The background layer has a non-transparent `background-color`), for now, the hotfix is possible via:

```js
map._getMap().setPaintProperty(map._getMap().getStyle().layers[0].id, 'background-color', 'transparent');
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a bug in a recent update. Please report these types of issues to the Azure support. In the Azure portal, go to your Azure Maps resource and at the bottom of the left side panel is an option to open a "new support request". I'll also reach out to people I know within the Azure Maps team to make them aware of this.